# How can i indent my html file with vim correctly?

Tags: vim, xhtml, html

I set up the indentation in my vimrc in the following way:

```
  set tabstop=2
  set shiftwidth=2

  set autoindent
  set indentexpr
  set expandtab
```

I created the indent folder in my ~/.vim/ directory and pasted an html indentation-plugin into ~/.vim/indent/ . I'm using the following one:

```
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2075
```

Whenever i try to "gg=G" in normal-mode it deletes all the indentation instead of indenting the file in a proper way. JavaScript files for example work nicely with another indentation plugin i have found, but nomatter which html plugin i have used so far, it didn't really work in a useful way.

Is there anything i can do here?

///////////////
Update:
i just tried to change the filetype to xml and it began to work. Now i'm asking myself how i can get this to work with html files. Hope someone can help me out.

## Heading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works out of the box for me. Try if it works with the minimal setup:

```
$ vim -u NONE
:set nocp
:filetype indent on
:set ft=html
```

and type in some HTML code.

The second tag should be indented by a tab now.

Comment: thx very much, a complete reset helped actually, because now i know that it functions by default. I will have to go trough my settings and see what exactly might brake this behavior.